# Is there a VPN client for Kali?

Tags: vpn, kali-linux

I'm pentesting a network using Kali Linux, however, sometimes I have to be outside the network. I'd like to perform this via VPN if possible, else I have to drive home each time (10 miles, 15km) which is a waste of a lot of my time.

Is there any VPN client available for Kali Linux? It should have PPTP.

Answer (score 2):

1. By default , VPN is not configure in Kali Linux. If you want to connect via VPN in Kali Linux, first install `pptp` and network `openvpn` using `apt-get install`.

   Command :

   ```
   apt-get install network-manager-{openvpn-gnome,pptp{,-gnome},strongswan,vpnc{,-gnome}}    
   /etc/init.d/network-manager restart
   ```

   (Make sure there are no spaces within the braces)
2. Cisco VPN Client also can be used in Kali Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can install and configure VPN on Kali Linux:

```
# apt-get update
```

then install plug-in (this one will also)

```
# apt-get install network-manager-pptp
# apt-get install network-manager-pptp-gnome
```

Or

```
# apt-get install network-manager-openvpn
# apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome
# apt-get install network-manager-pptp
# apt-get install network-manager-pptp-gnome
# apt-get install network-manager-strongswan
# apt-get install network-manager-vpnc
# apt-get install network-manager-vpnc-gnome
```